# MVC error path cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two questions: **1)** I am get the list of record from the database and displaying on a index page as a table. But I get this error: `Additional information: The argument 'path' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.`
This is my controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Records m = new Records();
        var Records = db.Records .Include((m.Types).ToString());
        return View(Records .ToList());
    }
```

In my modal:

```
public partial class Records 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Types{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }

}
```

**2)** I have created my models from the database using .edmx file, I would like to apply validation to above fields. I can do this by `[required]public Nullable<int> Types{ get; set; }` etc... but I future if I decide to change anything from my database and then perform a update to my .edmx file then all the [require] labels would be gone. How would I solve this problem'
Route Config File

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: @BradChristie I am new to MVC can you tell me where can I find `RouteConfig.cs`

Comment: Generally `~\App_Start`. If you don't have one (may be using an older MVC) check your `Global.aspx.cs` file for anything pertaining to `RouteCollection` (generally `routes.MapRoute(...)`)

Comment: @BradChristie found it, and I've included in question

Comment: Oops, I'm apparently coffee-deprived this morning. ;-) Here I am thinking "path" was a reference to a route issue, but it's actually because the `.include()` is being passed a bad value. With that said, try setting `(m.Types).ToString()` to a variable first, then step through the code and see what that value is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Part one: Working out details in comments above*

---

As far as validation, it's a good idea to establish separate models to be used through MVC and not pass your database models. A lot of times it may be one-to-one, but sometimes it's not (keep secure information out of the wrong hands). With that said, there are libraries like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) that make this easy (thankfully).  For example, given your model:

```
public partial class Records 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Types{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a view model:

```
public class RecordsViewModel
{
    [Required, HiddenInput]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required, Range(1,100)]
    public Nullable<int> Types{ get; set; }
    [Required, DataType(DataTypes.DateTime)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then map them using something like:

```
Records m = new Records();
var records = db.Records .Include((m.Types).ToString());
IList<RecordsViewModel> = Mapper.Map<IList<RecordsViewModel>>(records);
return View(RecordsViewModel);
```

Comment: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` and `Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: Try `records.ToList()` within the `Mapper.Map<>()` call (you may also want to read up on AutoMapper as they give a lot of examples of how it's done).